# Managing multiple environments with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, production-environment, digital-ocean, staging

I want to setup 2 droplets at digital ocean, and I'm thinking about use Vagrant to handle the configuration.

It looks like a good way to go, once digital ocean provides both the box and the "runtime"/provider environment.

I was thinking about having a staging droplet/env where I would use chef to install tools like nginx, ruby, etc.

When vagrant provision/recipes works ok, I would like vagrant to run the provision again, but now targeting my production droplet/env.

How can I achieve this behavior? Is it possible? Do I need to have multiple folders in my local machine? (e.g, ~/vagrant/stage and ~/vagrant/production)

Thank you.

Comment: it is possible, and vagrant supports to set multiple hosts in one `Vagrantfile`. Go through the vagrant document first.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to revisit your actual deployment use case, I doubt you want to unconditionally provision & deploy both the staging & production droplets at the same time.

If you'd like to provision a Digital Ocean droplet to use as your development environment, there is a provider located [here](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean)

A more common strategy would be to provision your environment locally (using Ansible, Chef etc) and then use `vagrant push` as a way to create an environment specific deployment i.e `vagrant push staging` provisions and deploys against all host marked as a staging server. [Inventories](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) within Ansible cover one way to describe this separation.

Comment: I do not intend to unconditionally run provision in both droplet at the same time. I was thinking about write recipes, change configurations, etc, and then run provision into staging droplet. It would be tested, fixed, changed, and once it's ok, then I would run provision into production droplet.

Comment: Using a simple example, I would like to do just like with github and heroku: `git push github master` to save changes in my remote repo vs `git push heroku master` to deploy.

Does something like this exists? `vagrant provision staging_droplet` and `vagrant provision production_droplet`?

Comment: Setting up `vagrant push` hooks per environment will result in a simialr flow: `git push github master` && `vagrant push testing`